# how can i dual boot with an already ubuntu computer if i have a harddrive i took out of a windows laptop with all its info on it?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

ive looked and looked but cant find anything but repartitioning and creating both on one harddrive. what i want to do is take my built computer that i have ubuntu 13.10 (updating to 14.04 as im typing this) and make it possible to choose my laptop harddrive at boot. which by the way is already plugged in and i can access the information but cant run anything with it being windows. this should be really easy shouldnt it? i mean i should be able to just simply pick which hd to start up from each time? please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two hard drive that you want to boot from, you can choose the boot device through the BIOS boot menu. To enter the BIOS menu press `esc` or `F-something` during boot (depends on system). Then select the hard drive you want to boot from. BIOSes are very system specific, so I can't really provide much more detailed instructions.

If I read your question right, you want to take a drive with Windows installed and slap it into a different computer. I'm pretty sure this will not work. You would have to reinstall Windows once you put it in the new machine.

Comment: why though? cause the harddrive is what holds the os. so why cant i boot from any harddrive i want?